# is "effective" the correct adjective in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, vocabulary, sentence-structure

This is my sentence:

> A study  shows that item-item approach is less affective to shilling attack than User-User approach.

To understand that sentence, you'd need to know what shilling attack is. It is where people provide high ratings for their products, and lower ratings for the other products (usually competitors’ products).

I am trying to say that user-user approach is better than item-item to deal with shilling attack

Comment: You've got *effective* in the title, but *affective* in the example (these are very different words). The correct phrasing is *A is less **effective against** attack than B* if you mean A isn't as good as B in terms of being able to resist attack. Or *A is less **affected by** attack than B* if you mean attacks either happen less often to A, or cause less (damaging) changes to A than they do to B. But if this is hard to follow, forget *effect/affect* and just say one is more ***resistant*** to attack than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "effective" would be correct, but the sentence needs some alterations, perhaps:

> A study [reference] shows that an item-item approach is less effective in preventing a shilling attack than a user-user approach.

The word "User" should not be capitalised unless you are using it as a proper noun, which does not appear to be the case here.

I added the indefinite articles "an" and "a" to make it read more naturally. However, if you are referring to one particular item-item approach and one particular user-user approach then "the" would be the correct definite article to use instead:

> A study [reference] shows that the item-item approach is less effective in preventing a shilling attack than the user-user approach.

It is probably a good idea to explicitly state that the intention is to prevent shilling attacks.

Finally, if you mention a study, you should give a reference to it so that readers can confirm its conclusion for themselves.